# When I apply the groupby function of pandas I don't get a dataframe but a strange output

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

This is an example of my dataframe and I would like to apply the `groupby` function but I get the following output:

Example dataframe:

```
x      sampling time    y
1        morning        19 
2        morning        19.1
3        morning        20
1        midday         17
2        midday         18
3        midday         19
```

Output:
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x11F3DEB0>

My code:

```
file = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/...
               r'2021_Licor_sinusoidal.xlsx')

df = file[['x', 'Sampling time', 'Y']].copy()
df.columns = ['x', 'Sampling time', 'Y']

grouped = df.groupby(['Sampling time'])
print(grouped)
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: It returns a grouped iterator which can be used to either use with inbuilt function like `sum()` or any custom UDFs. [groupby documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas' `groupby` is lazy in nature, which means that it doesn't return any actual data until you specifically ask for them. As mentioned in the comments, this returns a grouped iterator, which can be used with inbuilt functions like `sum()` and `count()`. [This](https://realpython.com/pandas-groupby/) tutorial will give you more insight regarding the operation and the way it works.

In a little more detail:

```
by_state = df.groupby("state")
print(by_state)
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x107293278>
```

Here you get the 'strange' object/output you mentioned, since `groupby` delays the split-combine-apply process until you invoke a method on these data, as mentioned above. Since the function returns an iterator, you can of course iterate on this.

```
for state, frame in by_state:
    print(f"First 2 entries for {state!r}")
    print("------------------------")
    print(frame.head(2), end="\n\n")

# First 2 entries for 'AK'
# ------------------------
#      last_name first_name   birthday gender type state        party
# 6619    Waskey      Frank 1875-04-20      M  rep    AK     Democrat
# 6647      Cale     Thomas 1848-09-17      M  rep    AK  Independent

# First 2 entries for 'AL'
# ------------------------
#     last_name first_name   birthday gender type state       party
# 912   Crowell       John 1780-09-18      M  rep    AL  Republican
# 991    Walker       John 1783-08-12      M  sen    AL  Republican
```